# Thread : Execute complete method having thread , once execution of method is completed start another method

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I have to execute 2 methods

1. `await()`
2. `signal()`

The condition is that after completing execution of method `await()` then only the method `signal()` should be called.

In my case the application is getting force close.

**I have written the sample example here:**

```
    private final Object lock = new Object();

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    signal();
    try {
        await();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("Method: after await");
}

public void signal() {
    synchronized (lock) {
        System.out.println("Method before ");
        **lock.notify();**
        System.out.println("Method await after signal ");
    }
}

public void await() throws InterruptedException {
    // synchronized (lock) {


    Thread t = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("Method await before wait ");
            try {
                **lock.wait();**
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                System.out.println("Method in exception ");
            }
            System.out.println("Method await after wait ");
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: `Please provide the solution` is not what SO is for. If you have a specific problem you aren't able to solve yourself though we will be happy to help.

Comment: I appretiate your comment  Keppil, I tried a lot for this but always getting InterruptedException exception , I solved this problem by creating two different classes but i need some help regarding the same logic i posted here , If you can help it out its appreciable .. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok, there are a number of problems here:

- You never start your `Thread`. Add the line

  ```
  t.start();
  ```

  after creating the `Thread`.
- The `wait()` isn't called from synchronized code. This gives me a `IllegalMonitorStateException` when trying to execute your code.
- You probably want to call `await()` before `signal()`, and also wait for a second or so in between, to make sure that the `await()` gets the lock first. If it doesn't, the program will block.

Comment: yes you are absolutely correct , i want to call await() first and then signal() and i started the thread t.start() but still i m getting the exception

Comment: @dhir: I'm sorry, I can't reproduce your error using the above code, it works fine for me.